# MySql time duration for Insertion,deletetion, Updation

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL server version 5.1 and we have nearly 200,000 records. I need to know how long MqSQL queries will take to complete for insertion, deletion, updates, and selection. Can anybody help me?

Comment: 1 lakh = 100,000. Kumar, this is an English web-site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before of your query , you should use

```
$start = microtime(true);
 //then your query

$end = microtime(true);
$duration=$end-$start;
 echo $duration;
```

may be its can work.

Answer (score 1):

Record the time before the operation, perform the operation, and record the time after the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try out [MySQL's query profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) or you can simply measure it with PHP.